# Create VSTO install package using VS2013 Installer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, vsto

I have tried to create a package for a VSTO addin using windows installer in Visual Studio 2013 but having no success. By that I mean I can create a exe and msi by using the Visual Studio Installer Setup Wizard and selecting everything as default, which seems to all run ok when installed but I don't get my addin appear anywhere in Word (I have looked in File-Options-Addins- com addins/dissabled addins).

I have spent quite a lot of time googling to find some instructions but with no success. Can anyone please help me by either writting some instuctions on here or pointing me to a link where someone has already done it?

Can I point out, I know how to create a package using Installsheild instead but I was having a few issues with that, so wanted to try this instead. So please don't suggest that as an approach, or wix.

Comment: Do you add [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386106.aspx) in the custom actions of your installer?

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which version of Word you're using. Traditionally, this has been a nightmare - but I would guess that the most horrible things has been fixed in more recent versions of Office. In particular I'm thinking of the "KB908002" which had to be applied during setup (don't know if that is the case still).

One thing that may be forgotten is that you are required to install the "Microsoft Primary Interop Assemblies" (PIA) on the target machine, and that you have to apply the correct PIA depending on which version of Office you have on the target machine.

Anyway, this article http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsod/archive/2008/04/22/troubleshooting-com-add-in-load-failures.aspx will give you quite a few ideas. Specifically, enabling the Fusion logging which has help me way back.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Dan. I have tried using both Word 2010 and Word 2013 but neither work. I will have a read through the link but where in the package do I need to apply the PIA's? I know I needed to specify them in a previous wix package, but I didn't have to do so for the InstallSheild (but maybe these were set by default somewhere in the package) so I wasn't expecting to need to set them for Visual Studio Installer

Comment: You should try to install the correct PIA first of all. In order to figure out if that is your problem, you could try to install it manually first and then run your installer. If it succeeds - then you know what the problem is. I asked myself about this once upon a time: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689106/net-deploying-office-2003-redistributable-primary-interop-assemblies-o2003pia

Comment: Otherwise, start with enabling the fusion logging.